# Returning values in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Following is the function in controller which returns the values of a product

```
public function productsAction()
     {

            $sku=$this->getRequest()->getparam('subvalue');
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

            $upsell_product_collection = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
            $upsel=$upsell_product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('product_type')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', 133);

            $products1 = $_product->getData();
            return $products1;
     }
```

Below is the ajax request for fetching the values at the frontend

```
$.ajax
  ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('finder/index/products');?>",
      data:"subvalue="+subval, 
      success: function(response) 
      {     
             alert(response);
            $("#responseproducts").html(response);

       };
  });
```

I m not able to fetch the values in the front end ..Please tell me ways to fetch the values at the front end

Comment: are you getting any js error?

Comment: try to return value as json. follow this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16216/how-to-get-json-data-on-frontend-in-magento/16238#16238

Comment: not getting any js error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your ajax request is sent successfully then add this code in you controller action.

```
$response['prodcutdata'] = $products1;
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
return;
```

After that in ajax request success access it like below:

```
alert(response.prodcutdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Decode as JSON in php:

```
return json_encode($products1);
```

and decode it in javascript:

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

This should work. You can test it afterwards with:

```
console.log(response);
```